# Confusion on the Symfony 4 upload documentation

Tags: symfony, file-upload

I'm learning Symfony 4 right now and I came across this documentation about file upload in the controller page that I got confused.

```
public function new(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // $file stores the uploaded PDF file
        /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
        $file = $product->getBrochure();
```

On form submission, *$file* was used to store the content of the uploaded file as specified by the annotation. But what's the point of this *$product->getBrochure()*? *$product* should held nothing inside since it was newly created from the Product entity.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you generate a form with an underlying object to store the data which is the Product Entity. The controller can be accessed on two ways.

first in the GET method without any form data and second in the POST method with data from the form fields. In Symfony the data from the form fields will be placed in your entity automatically and even validated automatically. It all happens with the line

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

So the uploaded file data is stored in the entity too and if you want to access it you will have to get it out of the entity by a public method like $product->getBrochure();

Comment: These implicit actions seem so odd to me. But still doesn't the annotation above it get the $file already?

Comment: It seems odd because you are new to Symfony. Later on you will discover the power of entities and get used to this kind of behavior, Aren't file uploads not a bit odd in PHP already?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the documentation in the Symfony 4 File Upload page is incorrect. This might be a little late for you, but the problem still exists. 
Instead of using:

```
$file = $product->getBrochure();
```

use:

```
$file = $form['brochure']->getData();
```

The first will return the file name which is a string while the second will get the actual file.